# javascript or jquery to extract integer out of html markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm trying to extract the second integer from inside the below markup.

```
<div class="orbit-slide-number">
   <span>1</span> 
   of 
   <span>3</span>
</div>
```

If  I try `$('.orbit-slide-number span:last-child')` it returns: `<span>3</span>` which is close, should I strip the span tags and call it a day?  Not that great with javascript.

(END GOAL: I'll be taking the integer and running some simple math 1000/integer -- using that math to dictate a width of a new element.)

Comment: There are no tags. When your HTML reaches the browser, it's parsed into a DOM. What you want is to extract the value of the nested text content of the `span` node. The tags you see are a rendering. In other words, the node is analysed and *turned into* an HTML representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
var x = $('.orbit-slide-number span:last-child').text();
console.log(x);
```

This will output: `3`.

If you want reference `x` as an integer in can use:

```
+x //returns numeric representation of x
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the 3 as string:

```
$('.orbit-slide-number span:last-child').text();
```

But if you want to use it for some math, you'll need an integer/number

```
var val=parseInt($('.orbit-slide-number span:last-child').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
var secondValue = $('.orbit-slide-number span:last-child').html();
```